# C# - Resizing jagged arrays with references

Tags: c#, resize, ref, jagged-arrays

I have written a small project which will read multiple CSV-Files into a jagged array (each csv in 1 jagged array).
All of the Arrays will be stored in a List. After that I have a given dimension I want to resize each array to (with given columns and rows).
The code:

```
    private void resizeArray( double[][] matrixToResize, int maxRow, int maxColumn)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref matrixToResize, maxRow);

        for (int i = 0; i < matrixToResize.Length; i++)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref matrixToResize[i], maxColumn);
        }
    }

    private void resizeArrayList(List<double[][]> csvList, Dimension dimension)
    {
        foreach (Double[][] matrix in csvList)
        {
            resizeArray(matrix, dimension.Max_Rows, dimension.Max_Columns);
        }
    }
```

`resizeArrayList` will be called 1. and this will then call `resizeArray` to resize the rows and after that resize for each row the given amount of columns.

**My Problem:**
In `resizeArray` it all works well, for example:
I have a array of 5 rows and 5 columns and want 10 rows and 10 columns,

i first size this array to 10 rows and after that each row to 10 columns. Before `resizeArray` returns to `resizeArrayList` it looks fine, i have 10 rows with each 10 columns. But after the Code falls back to the method `resizeArrayList` it has 5 Rows with 10(!) columns each. So basically the Columns resizing works fine, but the 5 added Rows are gone, its back to its original size of rows.

I know I could solve this with passing the whole jagged array back and reading this one to the list. But why is this the case?

Both times I use the resize function with the ref. But it just saves the columns and not the resized rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass `matrix` variable by reference, because reference itself is being modified in the `resizeArray` method. In the way in which you're doing it, all elements of the `csvList` list remain the same - arrays of length 5 - because `csvList` still consists of old references, those before resizing.

However, `matrix` is the loop variable and you cannot change it inside the loop, which means that you cannot pass it by reference to `resizeArray`. For that reason, I think you'll be better off creating an entirely new list as the result:

```
private double[][] resizeArray(double[][] matrixToResize,
                               int maxRow, int maxColumn)
{
    Array.Resize(ref matrixToResize, maxRow);

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixToResize.Length; i++)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref matrixToResize[i], maxColumn);
    }

    return matrixToResize;
}

private void resizeArrayList(List<double[][]> csvList, Dimension dimension)
{
    csvList = csvList
        .Select(matrix => 
            resizeArray(matrix, dimension.Max_Rows, dimension.Max_Columns))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! thank you so much for clearing this one up, i was quite confused! THANKS! have a nice day